# p5.play.js loadAnimation not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been trying to load frames that I've created for an animation to play using the loadAnimation() function from p5.play. This is what I've used.

```
sequenceAnimation = loadAnimation("img/frame01.png", "img/frame240.png");
```

In the API it says the first parameter is the fist frame of the animation and the second is the last. However, it just skips between the first and last without using the other frames. Example below:

https://editor.p5js.org/Mitch/present/r0BrZ3PxG

Any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: Add a complete working example that demonstrates the issue and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you linked, the start and end frames are renamed and end up being non-sequential because of the way the website works. When you check the inspector you'll see that your code becomes:

```
function preload() {
  sequenceAnimation = loadAnimation("https://assets.editor.p5js.org/59ca45fd5fd4073fbd453026/f8c445cc-effb-4287-90d5-aa2a4386b1df.png", "https://assets.editor.p5js.org/59ca45fd5fd4073fbd453026/9f509223-2634-4d19-ad0e-f966f2a917e8.png");
}
```

So the p5.play library assumes the animation is only two frames long.

Comment: That example was just to show what it was doing. Even in the editor where I specifically say frame1 and frame240 it still doesn't get the in-between frames.

Comment: The editor throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadAnimation is not defined (sketch: line 4)` and that's a different issue.

Comment: ... Still, the images also get renamed "under the hood" in the editor.